# Ansible WinRM: Bails out with "[Errno 111] Connection refused"

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

When i try to connect to my windows host via WinRM module i get execption "Connection refused" in Ansible.

There is structure of ansible direcory:

**Command:**

```
user@ansible:~/git/ansible-test$ ansible-playbook test.yml -i inventories/hosts 

PLAY [install vm] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.10.10.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.10.10.10', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6298184d50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))", "unreachable": true}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/git/ansible-test/test.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.10.10.10               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

**ansible-test direcroty hierarchy:**

```
ansible-test$ tree
.
├── group_vars
│   └── all
├── inventories
│   └── hosts
└── test.yml

2 directories, 3 files
```

**test.yaml:**

```
- name: test
  hosts: vm
  tasks:
    - name: get ipconfig information
      raw: ipconfg
      register: ipconfig_out
    - name: print stdout
      debug: var=ipconfig_out.stdout_lines
```

**inventories/hosts**

```
[vm]
10.10.10.10
```

**group_vars/all**

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_user: Administrator
ansible_password: password
```

But if i connect via WinRM from other windows host to the target 10.10.10.10:

```
 Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value 10.10.10.10
 Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName Administrator)
```

everything is ok!

What i do wrong in Ansible?

P.S.
Target host is Windows Server 2012

Comment: Hi user3265618, welcome to SO! It appears you have not set [`ansible_winrm_transport:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#authentication-options). I agree the connection refused is a strange message, but start by setting the correct transport and see if that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not configured the WinRM.

Fix:

1. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#winrm-setup
2. Add `ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore` in my group_vars file.

Comment: What if HTTP/S isn't working and HTTP is the only one that works?

Comment: Hi @FilBot3 - If only HTTP is working, then set the port to HTTP in groups_vars file.   <br />   Add `ansible_port: 5985`